# Prevent specific page from being redirected to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I need to avoid redirecting a page from my site to https, but I didn't want to use php, neither java, nor another programming language.

I would like to use .htaccess

On my website, I used the rule below in .htaccess to redirect all pages on the website to HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It works perfectly!

However, there are specific pages that I need to be in HTTP, as they display external content via iframe that comes in HTTP, and HTTP is not displayed within HTTPS.

I tried, add the code **no_ssl** to the end of the url

And I added the excerpt below in htaccess so that ssl would not be applied to urls ending with **no_ssl**

```
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ ([^n]|n[^o]|no[^_]|no_[^s]|no_s[^s]|no_ss[^l])$
```

So the complete code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ ([^n]|n[^o]|no[^_]|no_[^s]|no_s[^s]|no_ss[^l])$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So I expected that the page **mydomain.com/contact-no_ssl** would not be redirected to https. But it does not work.

I also tested the codes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)no_ssl$
```

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact-no_ssl.* [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But, noting works.

The maximum I got was to be redirected to the home page.

Can someone help me?

Comment: i try this, but doesnt work:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134721/redirecionamento-http-e-https-com-exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o/473630#473630

Answer (score 1):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !no_ssl[\s?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` since `THE_REQUEST` doesn't updated for a single request after application of other rules.